# If $t=xy$ then how to prove that $tx$=$xt^{-1}$

Tags: group-theory

Let $x$ and $y$ be elements of order $2$ in any group $G$.If $t$=$x$$y$ then how to prove that $t$$x$=$x$$t^{-1}$.

I know that in Dihedral Group of order $2n$ if $s$ be a refection across a line through a vertex then order of $s$ is $2$ and $r$$s$=$s$$r^{-1}$ where $r$ denote counterclockwise rotation by $2$$\pi$/$n$ radians.I think it may help to prove my above statement but I don't know how.Somebody please help me out.

Answer (score 4):

Since $x$ and $y$ have order $2$, we have $xyyx=e$. This means that $t^{-1} = yx$. Therefore $tx = xyx = xt^{-1}$.

Also, knowledge of the dihedral groups does not seem to help since you are asked to prove something for a general group.